# How to deactivate the touchscreen of android device?

Tags: android

i want to deactivate the touch screen of my android device for some application.
Anyone plz help me.......

Thanx in adv

Answer (score 3):

You cannot "deactivate the touch screen". You are welcome to design your own UI that does not respond to touch input.

Answer (score 2):

put a transparent Layout and override the OnTouch Events!

```
@Override
OnTouch():
 OnTouch(){
   return false;
}
```

Update::
[How to avoid Touch Event](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/1d83604da05ead9e)